# Escape special characters in flutter to be used in JSON request body

Tags: json, flutter, dart, encoding, escaping

I have a flutter based mobile application with a Nodejs based backend API's.

The mobile application contains:

1. Textfield inputs that support new lines, double quotes and other special characters.
2. WYSIWYG editor for user to type in rich text. (Similar to Stack Overflow Question editor)

I want to use the outputs of the above fields in JSON request body. But obviously I have issues with those special characters when backend API's try to parse the JSON request body.

I want to escape or encode/decode only the values of the textfields, not the entire JSON request body. I would like to parse those strings first and then pass the outputs to JSON request body.

1. I have tried jsonEncode() and jsonDecode() on the strings, which resulted in an exception.
2. I have tried Uri.encodeFull() and Uri.decodeFull(), which is a success.

But I would like to learn what is the best and effective practice out there to be used in such cases.

1. Should I continue using Uri.encodeFull() and Uri.decodeFull()?
2. When I encode/decode the strings, what form should be stored in database? Should it be encoded string or decoded string?

Comment: `jsonEncode` on the `String` should work.  What exception did you get?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @jamesdlin Here is the exceptioncustom_functions.dart:185 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.jsonEncode (custom_functions.dart:185:3) at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (dart_sdk.js:39921:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (dart_sdk.js:39957:7)
    at new_discussion_post_component_widget.dart:485:46
    at flutter_flow_widgets._FFButtonWidgetState.new.<anonymous> (flutter_flow_widgets.dart:110:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (dart_sdk.js:39921:34)

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that generated that exception.  If you're getting such an exception, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].